# Need help deciding what test to use

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, chi-squared-test

So I have 110 participants in a survey. Each participant was given the same 7 pieces of information and then asked to rate how that piece of information was more or less likely to do a task on a 10 point scale. They were asked this each time they were given a piece of information.

So my independent variables are the 7 pieces of info. My dependent is the measure of influence. The way they were asked these questions makes it seem like a matched pairs type of test. I was wondering if there was a type of matched pairs analysis that would account for 7 independent variables?

Comment: Trying to compare the 7 pieces of info! Sorry that was a typo